# How to trace NAT traffic (port-forwarding) from guest VM back to host

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, virtual-machines, virtualbox, linux-kernel

I have a host and guest Virtual-Machine (VirtualBox) with NAT Networking with the following network interfaces.
How to trace traffic from **local IP** 10.0.2.15 i.e. **guest's IP** back to **Host** ?

**Host**
*Ubuntu*

```
ip route show
default via 192.168.68.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.56.0/24 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.1
192.168.68.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.68.104 metric 600
```

Here **192.168.56.0/24** is the interface for VirtualBox

**Guest**
*Also Ubuntu via VirtualBox VM*

```
vagrant@master:~$ ip route show
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 10.0.2.15 metric 100 
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 
10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100 
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.10 

vagrant@master:~$ ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::cf:fdff:feba:3806  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:cf:fd:ba:38:06  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 53179  bytes 67713452 (67.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11030  bytes 941487 (941.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fecd:ad09  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:cd:ad:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 79  bytes 9158 (9.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 83  bytes 7254 (7.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 352  bytes 22658 (22.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 352  bytes 22658 (22.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Virtualbox** redirects SSH Traffic from  `2222` on Host to ssh port `22` on guest via NAT networking of VirtualBox.

The ssh traffic via **tshark** shows on 10.0.2.15 from 10.0.2.2 once a new ssh connection is started via

```
vagrant ssh master
```

tshark output:-

```
 vagrant@master:~$ sudo tshark  -i enp0s3 -E header=y
    Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
    Capturing on 'enp0s3'
        1 0.000000000     10.0.2.2 → 10.0.2.15    SSH 90 Client: Encrypted packet (len=36)
        2 0.000717886    10.0.2.15 → 10.0.2.2     SSH 90 Server: Encrypted packet (len=36)
        3 0.000972600     10.0.2.2 → 10.0.2.15    TCP 60 37672 → 22 [ACK] Seq=37 Ack=37 Win=65535 Len=0
        4 0.263247999    10.0.2.15 → 10.0.2.2     SSH 178 Server: Encrypted packet (len=124)
        5 0.263826882     10.0.2.2 → 10.0.2.15    TCP 60 56982 → 22 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=125 Win=65535 Len=0
        6 0.733596788     10.0.2.2 → 10.0.2.15    SSH 90 Client: Encrypted packet (len=36)
        7 0.733862097    10.0.2.15 → 10.0.2.2     SSH 106 Server: Encrypted packet (len=52)
        8 0.734013429     10.0.2.2 → 10.0.2.15    TCP 60 37672 → 22 [ACK] Seq=73 Ack=89 Win=65535 Len=0
```

I want to be able to see this network packets on host and how this routing is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that 192.168.68.104:2222 is opened by VirtualBox process (you may verify that with `lsof -i TCP -Pn | grep LISTEN`).

To strictly answer your question - you may take a list of ports opened by VirtualBox (the incantation above) and sniff packets on them, however this only shows traffic initiated by the remote party.

A better approach would be to add another IP to your wlp0s20f3 interface and do one-to-one NAT to a dedicated VM IP (192.168.56.10) on its interface (vboxnet0). This way a VM gets its own IP address on host:

```
# HOST
# enable routing if it is not enabled already
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# add another IP to your external-facing interface; make sure this IP is not used
ip addr add 192.168.68.99/24 dev wlp0s20f3

# enable NATting for incoming traffic
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.68.99 -j DNAT --to 192.168.56.10

# enable NATting for outgoing traffic
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.56.10 -j SNAT --to 192.168.68.99


# GUEST
# disable the interface we won't need
ip link set enp0s3 down

# use host IP as default gateway
ip route add default via 192.168.56.1
```

Even better approach would be to use bridging (this would allow more transparent layer 2 networking), but because you use wireless interface (I assume so judging by the interface name) it cannot be done without ebtables tinkering.

PS: Please don't use `ifconfig`, it is obsolete. use `ip addr` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will upvote it for your helpful suggestions but I will wait for an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: You cannot filter traffic by PID under Linux, it is only available on `tcpdump` for MacOS AFAIK. There is also a possibility to use a dedicated network namespace, but that's way more complicated than the solution described above. You can however use `iptables`' UID matcher and LOG target, but that shows only a summary of packet, not the traffic itself.